# Autoformat Horizontal Rule Lines span multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2013

I often add a series of hyphens (-) to my work to create a horizontal rule line between different sections.  As expected, the hyphens automatically convert to a separator.

However, in some documents, the separator spans three lines of text (appearing as if I entered 3 consecutive separators).  Occasionally, it spans 2 lines as well, but the standard 1 and the untraditional 3 are the most common.  It even changes depending on where in the document I've added the hyphen characters.

I would like it to always and ONLY replace hyphens with a single line.

[image: Task Image with 3 lines]

I use Microsoft Office 2013, and I nearly always add these separators in Outlook Tasks.

I am not using tables, and as far as I can see, no part of the Task has a wider width than any other part I thought that maybe it was truly one separator that was word-wrapping in my window to span 3 lines, but I don't see that being the case -- it will even appear around and through other existing lines of text if there is existing text following the inserted separator.